Overlaying a maplibre basemap with a potree point cloud
I have an application where user selects a bounding box on a maplibre basemap, sends it to a backend service, and then receives a url from backend that basically points to a potree point cloud(generated by potree converter) for that bounding box region. Clicking on url opens target point cloud in potree viewer in a separate tab.
Is it doable to instead render point cloud on maplibre basemap itself?
